# Add color overlay to video background

Tags: css

How do you add a color overlay to a video like this, as seen [here](http://sanfrancisco.themerella.com/):

[image]

Here is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="home-top-video">
      <video autoplay loop muted width="100%">
        <source src="http://view.vzaar.com/2710053.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> Your browser does not support the video tag. We suggest you upgrade your browser.
      </video>
      <div id="home-text">
        <div><img src="http://marquesslondon.herokuapp.com/images/logo.ee1689ee.png"></div>
        <h3>LIFESTYLE</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#home-top-video {
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#home-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kggv3213/1/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can try pseudo element with gradient background:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}
#outer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#home-top-video:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:1;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(65, 0, 255, 0.4),rgba(255, 0, 232, 0.3));
}

#home-top-video {
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#home-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="home-top-video">
      <video autoplay loop muted width="100%">
        <source src="http://view.vzaar.com/2710053.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> Your browser does not support the video tag. We suggest you upgrade your browser.
      </video>
      <div id="home-text">
        <div><img src="http://marquesslondon.herokuapp.com/images/logo.ee1689ee.png"></div>
        <h3>LIFESTYLE</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You have saved my Life. Love you Temani Afif

Answer (score 10):

Keep it simple, just add

```
#home-top-video:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,0,255,0.2); //Change as per your requirement
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to pitch in and say that :before didn't work in my case, but using #id:after works great.

Answer (score 1):

the above answers dont work because of stacking issues or will cause stacking issues with video controls, headers, buttons, and other things...

another option is to add background-color to the container div id.

then toggle the opacity of the video.

like this:

```
<div class='vid-container' id='vid-overlay'>
<video class='video' controls autoplay muted>
<source src='https://yourvideo.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
</div>


#vid-overlay {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: rgba(204, 50, 250, 0.8);
}

.video {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: fill;
    object-position: center;

    opacity: 0.8;
}
```